# Removing Microsoft Office Lync 2013 silent

Tags: lync

I want to remove Microsoft Lync (silent) from all the client computers in our domain.

I've already tried removing it with the "msiexec-command", but then the whole office got a problem with the other applications.

So I just wanted to ask if there would be some other suggestions to uninstall Lync.

Answer (score 1):

```
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE15\Office Setup Controller\setup.exe" 
/uninstall LYNCENTRY /dll OSETUP.DLL /config c:\temp\config_uninstall_Lync_Basic.xml
```

Where `c:\temp\config_uninstall_Lync_Basic.xml` looks like this:

```
<Configuration Product="LYNCENTRY">

<Display Level="None" AcceptEULA="TRUE" />
<Setting Id="SETUP_REBOOT" Value="NEVER" />

</Configuration>
```

Here is the official reference
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205129.aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj204651.aspx